# Error in node js while fetching records from mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pug

**Routes:**

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res) {

    //connection.connect();
    var sql="SELECT * from users where username='"+req.body.user+"' and password='"+req.body.pass+"' LIMIT 1";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        //res.send('Your data is: ', rows);
        var str="Hi, <b>"+rows[0].name+"</b> ("+rows[0].email+")";

        sql="SELECT username,name from users ORDER BY name";
        connection.query(sql, function(err, datarows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //res.send('Your data is: ', rows+' <br/> All Users are : ', datarows.length+"<a href='/'>Login</a>");
            console.log(datarows);
            res.render('home.jade', {title: 'Home',result:datarows});
           /*---------------The above calling jade-----------------*/   
        });

        //str+="<a href='/'>Login</a>";
        //res.send(str);
        //connection.end();
    });
```

**Jade:**

```
extends layout

block content
    //p #{result}
    -var list=[ { username: 'rohankumar1524', name: 'Rohan Kumar' }]
    each item, i in result
        p test #{item.length}
        each role,j in item
            p #{role}
```

**Output**

```
test

rohankumar1524

Rohan Kumar
```

**unusual output**

```
function (parser, fieldPackets, typeCast, nestTables, connection) { var self = this; var next = function () { return self._typeCast(fieldPacket, parser, connection.config.timezone, connection.config.supportBigNumbers); }; for (var i = 0; i < fieldPackets.length; i++) { var fieldPacket = fieldPackets[i]; var value; if (typeof typeCast == "function") { value = typeCast.apply(connection, [ new Field({ packet: fieldPacket, parser: parser }), next ]); } else { value = (typeCast) ? this._typeCast(fieldPacket, parser, connection.config.timezone, connection.config.supportBigNumbers) : ( (fieldPacket.charsetNr === Charsets.BINARY) ? parser.parseLengthCodedBuffer() : parser.parseLengthCodedString() ); } if (typeof nestTables == "string" && nestTables.length) { this[fieldPacket.table + nestTables + fieldPacket.name] = value; } else if (nestTables) { this[fieldPacket.table] = this[fieldPacket.table] || {}; this[fieldPacket.table][fieldPacket.name] = value; } else { this[fieldPacket.name] = value; } } }
```

**Also this**

```
function (field, parser, timeZone, supportBigNumbers) { switch (field.type) { case Types.TIMESTAMP: case Types.DATE: case Types.DATETIME: case Types.NEWDATE: var dateString = parser.parseLengthCodedString(); if (dateString === null) { return null; } if (timeZone != 'local') { if (field.type === Types.DATE) { dateString += ' 00:00:00 ' + timeZone; } else { dateString += timeZone; } } return new Date(dateString); case Types.TINY: case Types.SHORT: case Types.LONG: case Types.INT24: case Types.YEAR: case Types.FLOAT: case Types.DOUBLE: case Types.LONGLONG: case Types.NEWDECIMAL: var numberString = parser.parseLengthCodedString(); return (numberString === null || (field.zeroFill && numberString[0] == "0")) ? numberString : ((supportBigNumbers && Number(numberString) > IEEE_754_BINARY_64_PRECISION) ? numberString : Number(numberString)); case Types.BIT: return parser.parseLengthCodedBuffer(); case Types.STRING: case Types.VAR_STRING: case Types.TINY_BLOB: case Types.MEDIUM_BLOB: case Types.LONG_BLOB: case Types.BLOB: return (field.charsetNr === Charsets.BINARY) ? parser.parseLengthCodedBuffer() : parser.parseLengthCodedString(); case Types.GEOMETRY: return parser.parseGeometryValue(); default: return parser.parseLengthCodedString(); } }
```

But when I use this **code** in **jade**

```
extends layout

block content
    //p #{result}
    -var list=[  { username: 'rohankumar1524', name: 'Rohan Kumar' }]
    each item, i in list // list in place of result
        p test #{item.length}
        each role,j in item
            p #{role}
```

The **output** is

```
test

rohankumar1524

Rohan Kumar
```

**which is expected**

**Why** this problem occurs, is any other `module` I have `install` by `npm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Jade**

```
extends layout

block content
    each item in result
        p item.username
        p item.name
```